# Highlight regex based text on Chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

how can i select (or inject html bold tag or color tag, etc..) on a chrome page to all words for example that starting with letter "A"?

Like skype extension, that select all telephone number... i want to do it with certain words.

[image]

any idea?

---

## edit

I've used `"<h1><font color='red'>$1</font></h1>"`

[image]

...and this is result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like user 160820 said, .replace is a good way to format text that accomplish a pattern.

You look for that pattern with a RegExp, and replace each occurrence with the formatted version:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(A.*?\b)/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Only you have to do this in a content script, injected automatically by the manifest as the "content_scripts" field rules, or programatically injected from a background page by

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:'yourContentHere.js'});
```

[see executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)

You'll need this way if you want to fire the formatting from an extension button: browser action or page action.

Comment: great!! It works! i'll edit my answer with a screenshot! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample RegEx for highlighing.

```
var content = document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML;
document.write(content.replace(/(A.*?\b)/g, "<b>$1</b>"));
```

but what does it exactly means on `Chrome tab?`

Comment: chrome tab because it's an extension that works only on chrome opened tabs.. I'll try.